# show percentages and Numbers both in a Stack Flot Chart

Tags: charts, numbers, bar-chart, flot, percentage

I try to create a bar chart with percentage numbers on each bar number.
the following is my code, I want the Percentage to be shown in bar Numbers, also Count of each item in the tool tip (vise versa) .
I've tried *stackedpercent* but it didn't work.

For example these are my percentage values for data:

```
        var dc20 = [[37, 0], [0, 1], [16, 2], [34, 3]];      
        var dc21 = [[58, 0], [0, 1], [80, 2], [62, 3]];     
        var dc22 = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3]];    
        var dc23 = [[5, 0], [100, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3]];     
        var dc24 = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3]];
```

and these values are for Count of records

```
        var dc20 = [[16, 0], [0, 1], [5, 2], [11, 3]];        
        var dc21 = [[25, 0], [0, 1], [25, 2], [20, 3]];       
        var dc22 = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3]];        
        var dc23 = [[2, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]];       
        var dc24 = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3]];
```

**Update** 
This is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2g9jph3/2/) link for that.

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or code snippet.

Comment: @Raidri thanks . I've solved duplicate bar numbers , but Updated my question,also add a fiddle. Could you please have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to add the counts as a seperate array:

```
var counts = [
    [16, 0, 5, 11],
    [25, 0, 25, 20],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
];
```

and use that in the `tooltipOpts`:

```
    content: function (label, xval, yval, flotItem) {
        return '%' + xval + 'which has ' + counts[flotItem.seriesIndex][flotItem.dataIndex] + ' records ';
    },
```

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2g9jph3/4/).